# Error 1004 when executing workbook.open in VBA multiple (>1000) times

Tags: excel, vba

My macro creates a class called clsCalc which opens an external workbook, performs some calculations in it and closes the workbook without saving (by design).

Each time the class is created for each calculation, the external workbook is opened and closed. After exactly 1425 iterations on 2 different machines, the workbook.open function refuses to open that external workbook and throws error '1004'. Manually attempting to open the workbook would fail as well and the only option is to restart Excel. It then runs another 1425 iterations and throws up the same error.

Is there any excel limitation that I am not aware of? Thanks.

Comment: Are you certain it's not just the 1425th file that has an error? What's the error message of the runtime error? Are you copying worksheets at any point?

Comment: It's just one file which is reopened  and closed 1000 times without saving. The error message says "Application-defined error".

Comment: There seems to be some kind of cache build-up that needs to be wiped at some point. Very unspecific, I know, but it's what I have at this point. The following link mentions something similar when sheets are copied: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/210684

Comment: That actually sounds very similar to my problem except that I am not saving the workbook after each iteration. I will try saving and deleting it.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could check the total no of characters of the files.

Answer (score 0):

Update:
Following [DanL's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3177855/danl) suggestion in the comment above (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/210684) the issue seems to be resolved by saving the file every 500 iterations (or any point before the error occurs). This will trigger some sort of "flush" in Excel's cache. The tool has now reached 2000+ iterations without throwing any errors so far.